# Getting values of radio input

Tags: php, radio-button

I'm making a site about cities in Germany. I'm trying to get the radio input values of two questions (direction: north, south, west, east and number of people living in the city: x > 1 000 000, x > 500 000, x > 100 000, x < 100 000). After people choose these criteria and click on Next "button" (div="submit") it will show them the list of cities in cities.php.

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="radio.css">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script 
src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js? 
config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML' async></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<h1>I'm looking for a city with:</h1>

  <ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="f-option" name="population" value="million">
    <label for="f-option">More than a million citizens</label>

    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="s-option" name="population" value="fivehundred">
    <label for="s-option">More than 500 000 citizens</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="t-option" name="population" value="hundred">
    <label for="t-option">More than 100 000 citizens</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="o-option" name="population" value="lessthanhundred">
    <label for="o-option">Less than 100 000 citizens</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
  </li>

<div id="direction">
<div class="container"> 
    <h1>I want the city to be in the:</h1>

  <ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="a-option" name="direction" value="north">
    <label for="a-option">North</label>

    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="b-option" name="direction" value="south">
    <label for="b-option">South</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="c-option" name="direction" value="west">
    <label for="c-option">Hard</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
  </li>

 <li>
    <input type="radio" id="d-option" name="direction" value="east">
    <label for="c-option">East</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
  </li>

</ul>
</div>

<a href="cities.php">
<div id="submit"> Next </div>
</a>

<?php
$population = $_POST['population'];
$direction = $_POST['direction'];
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var population = "<?php echo $population; ?>";
    var difficulty = "<?php echo $direction; ?>";
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'cities.php',
            data: {p: population, d: direction},
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
</body>
```

cities.php:

```
$population = $_POST['p'];
$direction = $_POST['d'];
...
```

The problem is that it shows an error of undefined indexes: p,d

Comment: var difficulty probably needs to become var direction

Comment: Additionally you don't have a <form> tag.